# fresh mediawiki 1.30 install file upload failed. Tried restart. Now mediawiki fails completely

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, mediawiki

After install on ubuntu 16.04, mediawiki was working.
An image upload was tried but the page generated this error:

```
Could not open lock file for "mwstore://local-backend/local-public..."
```

Tried the following bash command, and now mediawiki fails completely:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

The browser message I now get is:

```
This page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

The apache install still works at localhost.
The mysql install still works for command-line login.
I broke something but need a hint to fix what went wrong.

Comment: Fixed "This page isn't working", but don't know how.  Just ignore that part for now.  I did hours of research into first issue "Could not open lock file" and still need help with that.  Any help on that would be very useful.

Comment: Changed the images folder permission with "chmod a+w images".  That worked.  Thank you for considering the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know all the answers I need but this worked in the end:

```
$ chmod a+w /var/www/lib/mediawiki/images
```

Comment: A variant of this (simply 'images' when in the mediawiki directory) worked for me.